# How to merge child arrays of documents in Document DB database?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am using Azure DocumentDB NoSQL database with an ASP.NET MVC front end.

I have a Families collection (just as an example):

```
[
    {
        "FamilyName": "Smith",
        "Children": [
            {
                "FirstName": "John"
            },
            {
                "FirstName": "Mike"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "FamilyName": "Williams",
        "Children": [
            {
                "FirstName": "Mark"
            },
            {
                "FirstName": "Mark"
            },
            {
                "FirstName": "Peter"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Is there a way that I can retrieve a list of "Children" (e.g. List) in alpha order without looping through each family and building a separate list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what `JOIN` is used for:

```
SELECT c.FirstName
FROM Families f 
JOIN c IN f.children 
ORDER BY c.FirstName ASC
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Azure CosmosDB:
Error: "Order-by over correlated collections is not supported."